# 414. The request URL is too long. asp.net

Tags: c#, html, jquery

I'm getting the error "HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long." From the following article, I understand that this is due to a very long query string:

http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/iis/query-string-too-long

In web.config, I have maxQueryStringLength="2097151". Is this the maximum value?
In order to solve this problem, should I set maxUrl in web.config? If so, what's the maximum value supported?
What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: or you should use a different way to deal with your input.. like using the POST method instead of GET. the limit should be way lower than what you said! I would be concerned even if it was higher than 100!

Answer (score 1):

The GET request should never be this long. You need to change it to POST method instead since it was designed to transmit block of data such as forms.

[An excerpt from the RFC 2616: Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616)

> The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the
> entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource
> identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line. POST is designed to
> allow a uniform method to cover the following functions:
>
> - Annotation of existing resources;
> - Posting a message to a bulletinboard, newsgroup, mailing list, or
>   similar group of articles;
> - Providing a block of data, such as the result of submitting a
>   form, to a data-handling process;
> - Extending a database through an appendoperation.